# How to include content to ajax success code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my project, the success function of ajax has much content. I am going to make these content to a file which named textcsc.js. And include() method is called in ajax.

Before independence code which works successfully:

```
$(document).ready(function()
 { 
  $('#bbs td').dblclick(function (){
  .......
    $.ajax({
    dataType:'json',
    ........
    success:function(data)
    {
    var $myHtml=data.stPrc;
    $myHtml.find("label").filter(function(){return $(this).text()===stChr;}).parent().attr("class", "rightd");
    $myHtml.find('label:contains('+stChr+')').next('label:contains('+stTrnStr+')').parent().next().attr('class','rightd');
    $myHtml.find('label:contains('+stChr+')').next('label:contains('+stTrnStr+')').parent().next().children("div").eq(0).attr('class','speech right'); 
    $myHtml.find('label:contains('+stChr+')').next('label:contains('+stFinStr+')').parent().next().attr('class','rightd');
    $myHtml.find('label:contains('+stChr+')').next('label:contains('+stFinStr+')').parent().next().children("div").eq(0).attr('class','speech right');
    $myHtml.find('label:contains('+stChr+')').next('label:contains('+stHngStr+')').parent().next().children("div").eq(0).attr('class','speech right');
    ......
    }
   });
 });
 });
```

After all of $myHtml.find content was moved to textcsc.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
 { 
  $('#bbs td').dblclick(function (){
  .......
   $.ajax({
   dataType:'json',
   .......
   success:function(data)
   {
    var $myHtml=data.stPrc;
    include(textcsc.js);
    ......
   }
   });
  });
 });
```

It works fail, and I have tried:

```
<script src="textcsc.js"></script>
 $(document).ready(function()
 { 
  $('#bbs td').dblclick(function (){
  .......
  $.ajax({
  dataType:'json',
  ........
  success:function(data)
  {
   var $myHtml=data.stPrc;
   chgLftRig($myHtml);//chgLftRig() is in textcsc.js
   ........
    }
   });
  });
  });
```

It works fail again. And then I have tried another way:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
 $('#bbs td').dblclick(function (){
 .......
  $.ajax({
  dataType:'json',
  ........
 success:function(data)
 {
  var $myHtml=data.stPrc;
   chgLftRig($myHtml);
   ......
  }
 });
 function chgLftRig($myHtml)//in the $('#bbs td').dblclick(
 {
$myHtml.find("label").filter(function(){return $(this).text()===stChr;}).parent().attr("class", "rightd");
$myHtml.find('label:contains('+stChr+')').next('label:contains('+stTrnStr+')').parent().next().attr('class','rightd');
$myHtml.find('label:contains('+stChr+')').next('label:contains('+stTrnStr+')').parent().next().children("div").eq(0).attr('class','speech right'); 
$myHtml.find('label:contains('+stChr+')').next('label:contains('+stFinStr+')').parent().next().attr('class','rightd');
$myHtml.find('label:contains('+stChr+')').next('label:contains('+stFinStr+')').parent().next().children("div").eq(0).attr('class','speech right');
$myHtml.find('label:contains('+stChr+')').next('label:contains('+stHngStr+')').parent().next().children("div").eq(0).attr('class','speech right');
 }
});
});
```

It works fine, and I put chgLftRig() out of $('#bbs td').dblclick(), it fail again.

I don't know why $myHtml can not out of $('#bbs td').dbclick().

Comment: Did you include the new file into your html and after the jquery include?

Comment: Did you declare `include()` anywhere in your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as A.iglesias said, not all modern browsers use include syntax in their native interpreter, if you want to break your js code in that way i highly recommend to you use ES6 syntax and NPM handler

in ES5 , make functions, and divide inside js files, call them in the html syntax, before the current js (so the function is declared before use it)

```
<script src="jquery.js" ></script>
<script src="textcsc.js" ></script>
<script src="youajaxcall.js"></script>
```

and in your textscs.js :

```
function renderDataFromAjaxCall($myhtml){
    $myHtml.find("label").filter(function(){return $(this).text()===stChr;}).parent().attr("class", "rightd");
    $myHtml.find('label:contains('+stChr+')').next('label:contains('+stTrnStr+')').parent().next().attr('class','rightd');
    $myHtml.find('label:contains('+stChr+')').next('label:contains('+stTrnStr+')').parent().next().children("div").eq(0).attr('class','speech right'); 
    $myHtml.find('label:contains('+stChr+')').next('label:contains('+stFinStr+')').parent().next().attr('class','rightd');
    $myHtml.find('label:contains('+stChr+')').next('label:contains('+stFinStr+')').parent().next().children("div").eq(0).attr('class','speech right');
    $myHtml.find('label:contains('+stChr+')').next('label:contains('+stHngStr+')').parent().next().children("div").eq(0).attr('class','speech right');
}
```

inside your ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
  dataType:'json',
  .......
  success:function(data)
  {
   var $myHtml=data.stPrc;
   renderDataFromAjaxCall($myhtml)
   ......
  }
});
```

you can check [babeljs.io](https://babeljs.io/) and start to make a new js development use.
if you want to keep it in the old way, i recommend you to use a JS Design pattern like modular, [Design Patterns js](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)

Comment: It does not work as you said. $myHtml is html code from DB, and $.ajax() is in $('#bbs td').dblclick(); bbs is table id. if I define renderDataFromAjaxCall() in $('#bbs td').dblclick(), it works fine. But out of $('#bbs td').dblclick(), it work fail.So the same as <script src="textcsc.js" ></script>

Comment: In textcsc.php, there is a value fetch from session. I set the value to global,. and textcsc.js works fine

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType:'json',
  .......
  success:function(data)
  {
   var $myHtml=data.stPrc;
   $.getScript('textcsc.js', function(){
        addSomeData();
   });
   ......
  }
});
```

then inside of your textcsc.js file

```
function addSomeData(){
    console.log('some magic here')
}
```

Comment: It does not work as you said. $myHtml is html code from DB, and $.ajax() is in $('#bbs td').dblclick(); bbs is table id. if I define addSomeData() in $('#bbs td').dblclick(), it works fine. But out of $('#bbs td').dblclick(), it work fail.So the same as $.getScript() and <script src="textcsc.js" ></script>

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid include() is not a jquery or javascript function. If you want to isolate that code, you better create a function with that code and call it inside success.

You can have the function in another file, and import it in your .html file using  tags.

```
<script src="yourjsfile.js" ></script>
```